# Auto-adjust canvas by itself in all possible sizes

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, size

I have one canvas-fx code ("stars" coming from deep to front, all centered, simulating space-navigation; it was **not** done by me) that I want to put in one website as a background.

I want it so that when a user resizes the window (dragging to right or left or resizing or whatever), the effect can auto-adjust itself so that the stars always come from the center in any size or even changing the desktop resolution (I refer the FX can auto-reset by itself the same it does when rendering the webcode).

Also I want it so that the code can adjust itself to the size of the content of the body (i.e. adding content from up to down, etc).

Finally, how can I quit the bottom bar, leaving only the scroll bar from the right?

Here is the complete code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>FX TEST</title>
        <STYLE type="text/css">
            html, body {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            #Canvas2D {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
            }
            #content {
                z-index: 10;
                position: relative;
            }
        </STYLE>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function setup() {
                var fov = 150;
                var SCREEN_WIDTH = 1920;
                var SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080;
                var HALF_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
                var HALF_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
                var numPoints = 300;

                function draw3Din2D(point3d) {
                    x3d = point3d[0];
                    y3d = point3d[1];
                    z3d = point3d[2];
                    var scale = fov / (fov + z3d);
                    var x2d = (x3d * scale) + HALF_WIDTH;
                    var y2d = (y3d * scale) + HALF_HEIGHT;
                    c.lineWidth = scale;
                    c.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
                    c.beginPath();
                    c.moveTo(x2d, y2d);
                    c.lineTo(x2d + scale, y2d);
                    c.stroke();
                }
                var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas2D');
                var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var points = [];

                function initPoints() {
                    for(i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
                        point = [(Math.random() * 400) - 200, (Math.random() * 400) - 200, (Math.random() * 400) - 200];
                        points.push(point);
                    }
                }

                function render() {
                    c.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                    c.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
                    for(i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
                        point3d = points[i];
                        z3d = point3d[2];
                        z3d -= 4;
                        if(z3d < -fov) z3d += 400;
                        point3d[2] = z3d;
                        draw3Din2D(point3d);
                    }
                }
                initPoints();
                var loop = setInterval(function () {
                    render();
                }, 50);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="setup();">
        <canvas id="Canvas2D" width="1920" height="1080">NOT USING HTML5 SUPPORT</canvas>
        <div id="content">
            <z-index: 0></z-index:>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, **thanks a lot to** *@Loktar* for your inner support.

Now i had been working on the code that i will put in my own Official Website (relaunching it).

After the help of *@Loktar*, the problem was that **the vertically autoadjust was not working**, so *i changed this* :

```
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

*To this* :

```
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
```

*And this* :

```
SCREEN_HEIGHT = canvas.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

*Changed To this* :

```
SCREEN_HEIGHT = canvas.height = document.body.offsetHeight;
```

Now it centers good vertically too.

The second problem was that when you doesn´t give to canvas command an exactly number of size it doesn´t show scrollbars, so i fund an style code that after i adadpt to this fx, the way now you can now have scrollbars horizontally and vertically. What you need to do is to add this to the style of your website :

```
div.scroll
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

For after call it in the div of the content with a class, as you can see below :

```
<div id="content" class="scroll">
```

Now you will have scrollbars activated when needed. It was tested at Internet Explorer and Firefox and works. I hope it will help to apply to several other canvas codes.

Finally, here i left how the final code looks, and partially how it will look at my Official Website :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>FX TEST</title>




<STYLE type="text/css"> 
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#Canvas2D {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;

}
#content {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

div.scroll
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:scroll;
}
</STYLE> 


<script language="JavaScript">
function setup() {

    var fov = 150;
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    var HALF_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    var HALF_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
    var numPoints = 300;

    function draw3Din2D(point3d) {
        x3d = point3d[0];
        y3d = point3d[1];
        z3d = point3d[2];
        var scale = fov / (fov + z3d);
        var x2d = (x3d * scale) + HALF_WIDTH;
        var y2d = (y3d * scale) + HALF_HEIGHT;

        c.lineWidth = scale;
        c.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(x2d, y2d);
        c.lineTo(x2d + scale, y2d);
        c.stroke();

    }


    var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas2D');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    var points = [];


    function initPoints() {
        for (i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
            point = [(Math.random() * 400) - 200, (Math.random() * 400) - 200, (Math.random() * 400) - 200];
            points.push(point);
        }

    }

    function render() {

        c.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        c.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);


        for (i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
            point3d = points[i];

            z3d = point3d[2];
            z3d -= 4;
            if (z3d < -fov) z3d += 400;
            point3d[2] = z3d;


            draw3Din2D(point3d);

        }
    }

    initPoints();

    var loop = setInterval(function () {
        render();
    }, 50);

    window.onresize = function () {
SCREEN_HEIGHT = canvas.height = document.body.offsetHeight;
    SCREEN_WIDTH = canvas.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
        HALF_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
        HALF_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
    };
}

setup();
</script>

</head>


<body onload="setup();">

<canvas id="Canvas2D"></canvas>


<div id="content" class="scroll">
<z-index: 0>





</z-index:>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

### **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/nr8jr/)**

### **[Full screen demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/loktar/nr8jr/show/light/)**

Below are the modifications I made to make it work. First remove the size in your canvas element. Change it to

```
<canvas id="Canvas2D"></canvas>
```

Next here is what I use for my CSS when Im doing anything full screen with canvas.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Canvas2D {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And here is the JS required to make it all work

```
    // set the width and height to the full windows size
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    // Change to scroll height to make it the size of the document
    var SCREEN_HEIGHT = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

    // Make sure to set the canvas to the screen height and width.
    canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

// everytime we resize change the height and width to the window size, and reset the
// center point  
window.onresize = function () {
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = canvas.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    SCREEN_WIDTH = canvas.width = document.body.offsetWidth;    
    HALF_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    HALF_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
};
```

Comment: Add width and height to 100% too and it looks great. `#Canvas2D {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}`

Comment: @Loktar your answer helped me a lot, but it only shows till a resolution, beyond it, it stop drawing, i refer that using 1920x1080, doesn´t cober a full draw on screen. The answer from MiniRagnarok doesn´t helped me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @EHPDJFRANKY hmm.. Im confused by what you mean. So it doesn't show it on the entire screen? Even with using this link http://fiddle.jshell.net/loktar/nr8jr/show/light/ ? I can't think of a reason it wouldn't.

Comment: @Loktar Sorry, shows very good, what occurs is that when i render the first time and my last IE Window was closed with little size, and then i resize manually, it doesn´t fit, i need to press f5. At reverse mode, it doesn´t occur.

Comment: @Lokstar I think that it depends on the last IE Window size, before it was closed. If it is more little that what i want to see, and i want it bigger, i need to press f5, but in reverse mode, i refer resizing at amore litlle size it adjust very good.

Comment: Yeah might be something with IE, unfortunately where Im currently at I don't have IE9 or 10 to test it on :?

Comment: @Loktar i had tested it with Firefox and the same. Is there anything that can oblígate to the browser to put it at maximized size? Not fullscreen as pressing f11 but maximized window.

Comment: @Lokstar Another problem is that it can´t scrolldown when adding content to the body. Anyway, thsnks a lot for your answers and time.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying now. You need the canvas to stretch beyond the window size! @EHPDJFRANKY let me put something else together real quick.

Comment: @EHPDJFRANKY ok check out my edits and new fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/loktar/nr8jr/show/light/

Comment: @Loktar With your last change it doesn´t center at all, but it gives a solution for the first problem. It gives a solution for one thing but is not compatible with the second. Anyway, the last problem is why it can´t scrolldown for to see the content? Because i can see only the content at my resolution, but it can´t scrolldown.

Answer (score 0):

set the width and height of the canvas to 100%.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but. It doesn´t helped me.

Comment: so your saying, the issue is not making the canvas fit, its that you do not know how to get the size of the canvas back into the javascript.